# Change Label.Text on it's own click event during Runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

All I need is a field that can be renamed by users as they wish by just clicking on it, I am using a label as the control here, when ever user click on it user could be able to enter text in the label and when he click outside of the label that enter text would be saved as the label text.

[image]

Comment: can u please add ur sample code .. so we can identify what you exactly needed ... for more info. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think your problem is that you can't edit text in a label. As the name says, it's just a label. You will need Textbox or Inputform or sth.

Comment: maybe you can make your own Textbox look like Label control.

Comment: Okey so its better to use any other control?

Comment: TextBox cannot be used as it would be viewed as a label

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: ok will do it from next time onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick solution:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = null;
    if (label1.Controls.Count > 0)  // do we already have created our TextBox?
    {
        tb = ((TextBox)label1.Controls[0]);  // yes. set reference.
        // is it already visible? we got clicked from outside, so we hide it:
        if (tb.Visible) { label1.Text = tb.Text; tb.Hide(); return; };
    }
    else if (sender == null) return;  // clicked from outside: do nothing
         else  // we need to create the textbox
         {
           tb = new TextBox();
           tb.Parent = label1;     // add it to the label's Controls collection
           tb.Size = label1.Size;  // size it
           // set the event that ends editing when focus goes elsewhere:
           tb.LostFocus += (ss, ee) =>   { label1.Text = tb.Text; tb.Hide(); };
         }

    tb.Text = label1.Text;  // get current text
    tb.Show();              // display the textbox in place
}
```

It **embeds** a `TextBox` into the `Label`. Style the `Label` to be big enough for the expected user entry!

It expects no other controls to be embedded there.

If you need it more than once consider creating a custom editable label from this code!

Note that to work you need to click at a spot where focus can go, not just the empty space around. To remedy that you could code the Click event for the surrounding space, maybe like this:

```
private void unClickLabel(object sender, EventArgs e) {label1_Click(null, null);}
```

In the form constructor add this to all the 'outside' controls that won't take focus, like the `Form` or a `TabPage` or a `PicureBox` or a `Panel`:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.Click += unClickLabel;   
   tabPage1.Click += unClickLabel;   
   pictureBox1.Click += unClickLabel;
   ..
}
```

Note that the new `Label` text will not **persist** program runs! To allow that you need to store it in some outside user settings and load them at startup..

Comment: Hey i am a junior developer it would be very helpful if u explain it in detail

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: I have added a few comments and also updated the answer a little. If you have problems, please desribe them!

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own UserControl which contains one label and one textbox. Implement its functionality like you want.

I have created a sample usercontrol to give you an idea about it...

**Update:**

Follow these steps to use this custom control.

1. Right click on your project and click 'Add-> UserControl'
2. Name it 'EditableLabelControl' and click Add.
3. Go to 'EditableLabelControl.Designer.cs' and replace the partial class  **Code1** below.
4. Then go to 'EditableLabelControl.cs' and replace second partial class by **Code2** below.
5. Build your solution.
6. You should be able to add EditableLabelControl to your form(it will be shown in toolbox)

**Code1**

```
 partial class EditableLabelControl
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "label1";
        this.label1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.label1_MouseClick);
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.textBox1.Visible = false;
        this.textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Leave);
        // 
        // EditableLabelControl
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "EditableLabelControl";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 23);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    #endregion
}
```

**Code2**

```
 public partial class EditableLabelControl : UserControl
{
    public EditableLabelControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox1.BringToFront();
        textBox1.Focus();
    }


    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Visible = false;
        textBox1.SendToBack();
    }
}
```

Just add this EditableLabelControl to your form and it should work.

Comment: EditableLabelControl?

Comment: No. Just add above said class to your project and you should be able to add this control to your form.

Comment: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'atHotel.EditableLabelControl'; another partial declaration of this type exists C:\Users\Danish\Desktop\atHotel11-4-16\EditableLabelControl.cs 12 18 atHotel

Comment: public EditableLabelControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {   can i change this function name?

Comment: I've updated my answer. See if it works for you now.

Comment: Once the text is changed cant we set that text as the label so?  Becouase i want to have the changed text itself when the client repons it in this case it shows the deafault text

Comment: Yes you can. Just add `textBox1.Text = label1.Text;` in `label1_MouseClick` method before setting Visible property.

Comment: I mean when we load it one more time i want the last text to be shown as labels text, right now it is showing label 1 when every time i run the programme.  and i need to do it without saving the value in database

Comment: What do you mean by *"When we load it one more time"*?

Comment: You will have to save that text somewhere to use next time. Somewhere means like some database or file etc. Its not part of this question. If you need help in that, ask separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TextBox` instead of Label.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) control and set the `ReadOnly` property to `true`, if you would like to have a non-changeable text field. However, keep in mind, the TextBox will not resize automatically and does not support transparency.

You can change the property `BackColor` to `Control` and the `BorderStyle` to `none`, this will appear like a label.

With more effort you can create a UserControl and switch between the Lable and TextBox.

Comment: Can we set textbox  prop to trasnsparent just like the label only the text need to be visible for users

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using textBox instead.

Replace the label with textBox.

```
//Set properties. Make the textBox looks like label
yourTextBox.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
yourTextBox.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;

//Allow user to change text by double clicking it
yourTextBox.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(this.doubleClick);

//Do stuff when user double click it. Double click again to end editing.
public void doubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox temp = (TextBox)sender;
    temp.ReadOnly = !temp.ReadOnly;            
    temp.DeselectAll();
    if (temp.ReadOnly)
    {
        //Make the textbox lose focus
        this.ActiveControl = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: will it be transparent?

Comment: You cannot set the BackColor of textBox to transparent.

Comment: But setting the BackColor to SystemColors.Control means it has the same color as your form. So it looks "transparent".